# Submitting Entry Edits Routes to a Non-Existent Page

Tags: channel

Encountering a some odd issues attempting to submit changes on in the CP of an ExpressionEngine 2.7.2 site. Instead of saving the changes and displaying the success message, I'm bounced to a non-existent URL and the landing page of my site is displayed instead.

**URL FOR ENTRY:**

`/system/index.php?S=b6fd020cbb7cc1f54675bce25372a17b&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=1&entry_id=1&&filter=YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjEiO30=`

**URL FOR NON-EXISTENT PAGE**

`/system/index.php?S=b6fd020cbb7cc1f54675bce25372a17b&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=1&entry_id=1&filter=YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjEiO30%3D`

Notice how the first URL has double ampersands right before the filter (entry_id=1&&filter=) and the URL of the second domain ends not with an = sign but with %3D.

I've see this error in two separate instances:

1) In a particular textarea field (in a field group which only contains five fields), entering more than 327 characters will trigger the error — even if all of the other fields are empty.

2) Adding new fields to a channel field group, regardless of whether it's a brand-new field group or simply adding a field to an existing group.

Disabling extensions (via the config.php file) is having no impact and the logs are not giving any meaningful data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounced this issue up to EllisLab's private support. The answer might be unique to my host but the issue appears to be with their security measures.

The content in question happened to contain a phrase which spambots might use. The speculation is the host is using mod_security rules to prevent that phrase on index.php pages.

The recommended workaround is to use admin.php to log into the CP as that page is likely not blacklisted.

Again, your mileage may vary, but if future developers run into a similar issue... try admin.php.

Comment: This sounds about right... Were you able to confirm with the host?

Comment: I have not but from newsletters they've sent out recently, I know they are being proactive (maybe a bit too much) about keeping their servers less prone to spambot attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to a weird URL or some other piece of content in the entry. I've seen similar issues a couple times. Start removing copy a chunk at a time till you find it.

Comment: Hmm. The glitch seems to hit where one particular field (a textarea field) has over 327 characters. Hand typed in the content to avoid encoding issues; the text may have originally been copied and pasted from InDesign.

Comment: Interesting... it also happens if I try to add a new field to the channel group.